# Multidimensional array to CSV

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array, export-to-csv

I got this array:

```
array (
  'cat' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'name' => 'Sales',
      'url' => 'http://videos.volkswagen.nl/videos/videos/',
      'subs' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'full_url' => 'http://videos.volkswagen.nl/videos/assistentiesystemen/',
          'key' => 'assistentiesystemen',
          'key_clean' => 'Assistentiesystemen',
          'videos' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            array (
              'nice_name' => 'Multi Collision braking system',
              'vid_url' => 'www.youtube.com/video/3lGfTZdVK1s',
            ),
            1 => 
            array (
              'nice_name' => 'Lane Assist',
              'vid_url' => 'www.youtube.com/video/II68oVm4zro',
            ),
            2 => 
            array (
              'nice_name' => 'Traffic Jam Assist',
              'vid_url' => 'www.youtube.com/video/tCe8Zpz8ceQ',
            ),
            3 => 
            array (
              'nice_name' => 'Sign assist',
              'vid_url' => 'www.youtube.com/video/SypjMPcSWfk',
            ),
            4 => 
            array (
              'nice_name' => 'Park assist',
              'vid_url' => 'www.youtube.com/video/38BbjLmVJXk',
            ),
            5 => 
            array (
              'nice_name' => 'Front assist',
              'vid_url' => 'www.youtube.com/video/kCpQojqZeWE',
            ),
            6 => 
            array (
              'nice_name' => 'Trailer assist',
              'vid_url' => 'www.youtube.com/video/N0fa4dUBkvE',
            ),
            7 => 
            array (
              'nice_name' => 'Area view',
              'vid_url' => 'www.youtube.com/video/6mgDraWpGvE',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
          'full_url' => 'http://videos.volkswagen.nl/videos/comfortsystemen/',
          'key' => 'comfortsystemen',
          'key_clean' => 'Comfortsystemen',
          'videos' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            array (
              'nice_name' => 'Gesture Control',
              'vid_url' => 'www.youtube.com/video/bOejnFiC88E',
            ),
            1 => 
            array (
              'nice_name' => 'ACC Adaptive Cruise Control',
              'vid_url' => 'www.youtube.com/video/W5L75iR4ySw',
            ),
            2 => 
            array (
              'nice_name' => 'Rear View',
              'vid_url' => 'www.youtube.com/video/v272JxYMjlo',
            ),
            3 => 
            array (
              'nice_name' => 'Hill Hold',
              'vid_url' => 'www.youtube.com/video/IzZFSp0Z8ZQ',
            ),
            4 => 
            array (
              'nice_name' => 'Dynamic Light Assist',
              'vid_url' => 'www.youtube.com/video/mRWEdXZYcio',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

I want to convert all of the data to a csv file. The problem is, I can't seem to get it working because of all the sub arrays.

This is what I have tried:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"demo.xls\"");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
$out = fopen("php://output", 'w');
foreach ($result as $data)
{
    $finalResult = [];
    array_walk_recursive($data, function($item) use (&$result) {
            $finalResult[] = $item;
        });
    fputcsv($out, $finalResult,"\t");
}   
fclose($out);
```

This is how I want the csv file to look like in excel:

[image]

Any idea how I can get this working? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please update the question to show a line of CSV output you'd expect? How would you like to collapse multi-dimensional data down into two dimensions?

Comment: Also if you show us a `var_export()` instead of a `print_r()` we get an array representation we can copy/paste and easily test our answers. Those of us that bother testing our answers that is

Comment: Added an example @mkaatman

Comment: Edited @RiggsFolly

Comment: A CSV is comma separated values. One record per line. I don't see any commas in your output example and it doesn't look like any CSV I've ever seen.

Comment: Also `var_export()` is not complete? You help us, we will help you!

Comment: Sorry for the bad example, since I am exporting to excel I only know how it looks like in excel. Added example to the question.

Comment: What am I missing? @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably what you want to be doing

```
$out = fopen("tst.csv", 'w');
$finalResult = [];
foreach ($result['cat'] as $sales){
    foreach ( $sales['subs'] as $occ => $stuff){
        foreach ( $stuff['videos'] as $video ) {
            $line = [$sales['name'], $stuff['key'], $video['vid_url'], $video['nice_name'] ];
            //$finalResult[] = $a;
            fputcsv($out, $line);
        }
    }
}
//print_r($finalResult);
fclose($out);
```

Which produces

```
Sales,assistentiesystemen,www.youtube.com/video/3lGfTZdVK1s,"Multi Collision braking system"
Sales,assistentiesystemen,www.youtube.com/video/II68oVm4zro,"Lane Assist"
Sales,assistentiesystemen,www.youtube.com/video/tCe8Zpz8ceQ,"Traffic Jam Assist"
Sales,assistentiesystemen,www.youtube.com/video/SypjMPcSWfk,"Sign assist"
Sales,assistentiesystemen,www.youtube.com/video/38BbjLmVJXk,"Park assist"
Sales,assistentiesystemen,www.youtube.com/video/kCpQojqZeWE,"Front assist"
Sales,assistentiesystemen,www.youtube.com/video/N0fa4dUBkvE,"Trailer assist"
Sales,assistentiesystemen,www.youtube.com/video/6mgDraWpGvE,"Area view"
Sales,comfortsystemen,www.youtube.com/video/bOejnFiC88E,"Gesture Control"
Sales,comfortsystemen,www.youtube.com/video/W5L75iR4ySw,"ACC Adaptive Cruise Control"
Sales,comfortsystemen,www.youtube.com/video/v272JxYMjlo,"Rear View"
Sales,comfortsystemen,www.youtube.com/video/IzZFSp0Z8ZQ,"Hill Hold"
Sales,comfortsystemen,www.youtube.com/video/mRWEdXZYcio,"Dynamic Light Assist"
```