# Exporting an multidimensional array to a CSV document in Symfony

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, csv, export

There is such an multidimensional array (with n-nested),via print_r derived:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 829
    [name] => name surname
    [info] => Array
        (
            [direct] => 13
            [count] => 492
            [total] => 108
            [asoc] => 4.514
        )

    [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 530
                    [name] => name surname2
                    [info] => Array
                        (
                            [direct] => 6
                            [count] => 49
                            [asoc] => 3.267
                            [total] => 14
                        )

                    [_children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 628
                                    [name] => name surname3
                                    [info] => Array
                                        (
                                            [direct] => 1
                                            [count] => 1
                                            [asoc] => 1
                                            [total] => 0
                                        )

                                    [_children] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 2
                                                    [name] => Name..
                                                    [info] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [direct] => 0
                                                            [count] => 0
                                                            [asoc] => 0
                                                        )

                                                    [children] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )
                                             [1] => Array
                                                     (
                                                    [id] => 3
                                                    [name] => Name..S
                                                    [info] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [direct] => 1
                                                            [count] => 2
                                                            [asoc] => 1
                                                        )

                                                    [children] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )
```

I need to write it to a CSV file, keeping the structure (tree). The bottom line is that I tried many methods how to write this to a file, but for some reason I did not succeed (do not judge strictly, I'm new to this). The CSV document should have the following structure:

```
name surname (13, 492, 108,4.514)//в скобках это info из массива                
    name surname2 (6, 49,3.267, 14) 
    name surname3 (1, 1, 1)         
                  name surname4
                  name surname5(1,2,1)
```

I will be grateful for any useful information (or books) on this matter! Thank you!
I tried to do this:

```
foreach (new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveArrayIterator($structureTree)) as $key => $value) {
            fputcsv($file, array($value));
        }
```

but i receive this:

```
829
name surname
13
492
108
4.514
...
Name..S
1
2
1
```

**UPDATE**
I tried this to, but how I can make tree structure?

```
public function recursive($array, $file)
    {
        foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
            if (is_array($item) && $key === 'info')
                fputcsv($file, $item);
            elseif (is_array($item)) {
                $this->recursive($item, $file);
                fputcsv($file,array('-'));
            }
            elseif ($key == 'id')
                    continue;
                else
                    fputcsv($file, array($item));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, usually you don't use CSV to store trees... CSV is better used with matrices (2-dimension arrays / tables). Also, we need to see what you tried.

Comment: @Pawamoy, I tried to do this, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186845/multidimensional-array-to-csv) question. But since I have an array with n-nesting, it did not work out for me ...

Comment: You have to write a function that writes a line (name, surname, etc.) and then recurse on the children (i.e. the function calls itself again for each child).

Comment: @Pawamoy, can you, please, give some example, I know how to make recursion, but I don't know how to make tree structure...

Comment: I did not try your code but it seems you are close :) In the output you want, you add indentation to children. To do that with your recursive function, add a third parameter called for example `indent` or `level`. Each time you call the recursive function again, increase that level. And when you write to the CSV, use that level to know how many empty cells you need to add at the beginning!