# How to output multi-dimensional array to CSV file in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, csv, active-directory, ldap

I'm having a bit of an issue with converting my multidimensional array to a CSV file. The issue is that it also contains more arrays within the array.

I'm trying to convert the output of all the entries and attributes of an LDAP server into a CSV file.

A really similar question to mine can be found here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186845/multidimensional-array-to-csv)

Essentially, I'll need the same output as the excel spreadsheet in that question, except for my fields. The issue is that not every LDAP entry has the same attributes. So some of the boxes will be empty.

So for instance I'll have

`DN, ObjectClasses, Email, Phone Number, CN, UserID`

`cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com, top, email@gmail.com, 123-456-7890, training, 12345`

But some of my arrays don't have all elements, so for instance, they are missing an email or phone number, but the rest of the elements do have the email or phone number, so I can't manually just enter all the attributes. (Also can't do this as I don't know all of the attributes that the user will need).

Here's my current output:
 `Amount of entries: 23dc=example,dc=com,objectclass,top,dcObject,organization,example.com,example,cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com,objectclass,simpleSecurityObject,organizationalRole,admin,"LDAP administrator",uid=newton,dc=example,dc=com,Newton,objectclass,inetOrgPerson,organizationalPerson,person,top,newton,newton@ldap.forumsys.com,"Isaac Newton",uid=einstein,dc=example,dc=com,objectclass,inetOrgPerson,organizationalPerson,person,top,"Albert Einstein",Einstein,einstein,einstein@ldap.forumsys.com,314-159-2653,uid=tesla,dc=example,dc=com,objectclass,inetOrgPerson,organizationalPerson,person,top,posixAccount,"Nikola Tesla",Tesla,tesla,tesla@ldap.forumsys.com,88888,99999,home,uid=galieleo,dc=example,dc=com,objectclass,inetOrgPerson,organizationalPerson,person,top,"Galileo Galilei",Galilei,galieleo,galieleo@ldap.forumsys.com,uid=euler,dc=example,dc=com,objectclass,inetOrgPerson,organizationalPerson,person,top,euler,Euler,"Leonhard Euler",euler@ldap.forumsys.com`

Basically, it's just completely unorganized (don't mind the amount of entries: 23 part)

I was wondering how I could organize all my outputs?

Here's my current code:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $ldaprdn  = 'cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com';
  $ldappass = 'password';
  $ldapuri = "ldap.forumsys.com";

  // Connecting to LDAP
  $ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldapuri)
          or die("That LDAP-URI was not parseable");


  //We need to set the LDAP Protocol Version or else it isn't able to bind properly to the LDAP server.
  ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

  //We bind to the LDAP server using the previous credentials and location.
  $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);


  //Gives where to search & what to search for
  $dn = "dc=example,dc=com";
  $filter = "(objectclass=*)";

  //Saves the result into result variable
  $result = ldap_search($ldapconn, $dn, $filter);

  $info = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);

  //Saves all the attributes of all entries into an array.
  function cleanUpEntry( $entry ) {
    $retEntry = array();
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $entry["count"]; $i++ ) {
      if (is_array($entry[$i])) {
        $subtree = $entry[$i];
        //This condition should be superfluous so just take the recursive call
        //adapted to your situation in order to increase perf.
        if ( ! empty($subtree['dn']) and ! isset($retEntry[$subtree['dn']])) {
          $retEntry[$subtree['dn']] = cleanUpEntry($subtree);
        }
        else {
          $retEntry[] = cleanUpEntry($subtree);
        }
      }
      else {
        $attribute = $entry[$i];
        if ( $entry[$attribute]['count'] == 1 ) {
          $retEntry[$attribute] = $entry[$attribute][0];
        } else {
          for ( $j = 0; $j < $entry[$attribute]['count']; $j++ ) {
            $retEntry[$attribute][] = $entry[$attribute][$j];
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return $retEntry;
  }
  echo "Amount of entries: ".(sizeof(cleanUpEntry($info)));
  /*
  //Prints all the elements in the array
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r(cleanUpEntry($info));
  echo "</pre>";*/


  function array_flatten($array) { 
    if (!is_array($array)) { 
      return FALSE; 
    } 
    $result = array(); 
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) { 
      if (is_array($value)) { 
        $arrayList=array_flatten($value);
        foreach ($arrayList as $listItem) {
          $result[] = $listItem; 
        }
      } 
     else { 
      $result[$key] = $value; 
     } 
    } 
    return $result; 
  } 

    function arrayToValues(array $data)
  {
      $output = array();

      foreach ($data as $key => $item) {
          if (is_array($item)) {
              $output = array_merge($output, array($key), arrayToValues($item));
          } else {
              $output[] = $item;
          }
      }

      return $output;
  }

  $csvData = implode(',', arrayToValues(cleanUpEntry($info)));

  $csvExport = explode(',', $csvData);
  
  header('Content-Type: application/csv');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv";');

  $f = fopen('php://output', 'w');

  fputcsv($f, arrayToValues($csvExport));

?>
```

Comment: Is $info an array? can please clarify how the array looks like in your question?

Comment: Does this help? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-explode-dn.php